# Performance difference of one request and multiple requests in angular

Tags: c#, angular, performance, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular 6 project. And I have a form with 20 combobox and some textbox like below image. So, I'm binding combobox items while page loading. There is two approach for doing this like below.

[MY FORM IMAGE](https://ibb.co/cqmcS0)

### **FIRST APPROACH:**

**.ts file**

```
onInit(){
   let countries= this.http.get("getCountries");
   let cities= this.http.get("getCities");
   let states= this.http.get("getStates");
   let universities= this.http.get("getUniversities");
   let elementarySchools= this.http.get("getElementarySchools");
   let studentTypes= this.http.get("getStudentTypes");
   let universityTypes= this.http.get("getUniversityTypes");
   let genders= this.http.get("getGenders");
   let diseaseTypes= this.http.get("getDiseaseTypes");
   let accessTypes= this.http.get("getAccessTypes");
   let appealTypes= this.http.get("getAppealTypes");
   let computerBrands= this.http.get("getComputerBrands");
   let carTypes= this.http.get("getCarTypes");
   let positions= this.http.get("getPositions");
   let workingTypes= this.http.get("getWorkingTypes");
   let travelTypes= this.http.get("getTravelTypes");
   let feedbacks= this.http.get("getFeedbacks");
   let contactTypes= this.http.get("getContactTypes");
   let maritalStatus= this.http.get("getMaritalStatus");
}
```

**ApiController.cs**

```
public List<string> getCountries()
 { return new List<string>{"sgh","shd","dfh"}; }
public List<string> getCities()
 { return new List<string>{"agg","dfh","dfj"}; }
public List<string> getStates()
 { return new List<string>{"ghf","ghj","jhk"}; }
public List<string> getUniversities()
 { return new List<string>{"sdh","dfj","hgj"}; }
public List<string> getElementarySchools()
 { return new List<string>{"jhg","fdh","fsg"}; }
public List<string> getStudentTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"asf","sdf","fdh"}; }
public List<string> getUniversityTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"fdh","asd","tyr"}; }
public List<string> getGenders()
 { return new List<string>{"ewt","ret","uer"}; }
public List<string> getDiseaseTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"asd","zxc","vbn"}; }
public List<string> getAccessTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"wet","wtt","yrx"}; }
public List<string> getAppealTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"asd","zxc","vbn"}; }
public List<string> getComputerBrands()
 { return new List<string>{"asd","zxc","dfh"}; }
public List<string> getCarTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"asd","zxc","sdf"}; }
public List<string> getPositions()
 { return new List<string>{"asd","zxc","bfg"}; }
public List<string> getWorkingTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"dfh","zxc","dhj"}; }
public List<string> getTravelTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"hgj","zxc","jfd"}; }
public List<string> getFeedbacks()
 { return new List<string>{"khg","zxc","vbn"}; }
public List<string> getContactTypes()
 { return new List<string>{"cvn","zxc","gsh"}; }
public List<string> getMaritalStatus()
 { return new List<string>{"dfh","zxc","vbn"}; }
```

---

### **SECOND APPROACH:**

**.ts file**

```
onInit(){
  this.http.get("getAllComboboxBindingLists");
}
```

**ApiController.cs**

```
public List<List<string>> getAllComboboxBindingLists()
{
   var resultList = new List<List<string>>();
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"sgh","shd","dfh"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"dfg","fgh","dhh"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"hjf","gfh","sdf"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"sjf","ghj","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"agg","fdg","fgj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"nfd","ghj","fdg"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"ghj","dfh","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"ghk","hjk","ghj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"agg","yuı","gfh"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"ret","yuı","yuı"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"ghj","dfh","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"fjj","gfh","tyu"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"set","dfg","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"yru","tuı","try"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"tru","dfh","hjg"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"agg","wry","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"ghj","hjk","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"dfg","fgj","dfj"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"yjg","yır","rjf"});
   resultList.Add(new List<string>{"rwy","tru","ıtu"});
   return resultList;
}
```

## Advantages and disadvantage of first approach

- **Advantage:** We can use methods in other pages. Because every method has own method. Foreample you can call "getUniversityTypes" from everywhere.
- **Disadvantage:** We send 20 request to server

## Advantages and disadvantage of second approach

- **Advantage:** We send only one request to server
- **Disadvantage:** We can't use methods from other pages. Because in controller.cs, there is only one method and getting all values. So, you can't forexample only "getUniversityTypes"

### My Question

**Is there any performance difference of this two approach and how much?** Because, my application will be used by **million people** and there will be hundreds of page like this. And this performance difference is very important for me. (I think, first approach, will get tired to server because of 20 times request)

Comment: there's never going to be an answer to this question - only an `opinion`.  here at SO we try to help people with coding questions that have an `answer`

Comment: This is coding method. It's not another thing. If you want, I can ask, how can I getting combobox values in page? But, I especially wrote detailed. @JohnB In addition, this is not an opinion. I'm asking which method is proper way?

Comment: so how do `we` measure performance and give you an answer here? I think you have to do that yourself as you have the provisioned environment details we know nothing about.  any testing we do could be built upon false assumptions and misconceptions

Comment: All codes writing in question. You can run everywhere this codes. I wrote detailed. And experienced developer can easily know answer of this question. It's very basic question. I'm newbie at angular and service oriented. So, I don't know answer. @JohnB

Comment: you fail to accept that different environment will affect performance?  yes the code will run everywhere - but how fast?  only you know...because you know the environment which can have a heavy affect on HOW the code runs.

Comment: I wrote my technologies used from me. Asp.net Core webAPI and angular 6. If one of these approaches has more performance, then everywhere will give the same result. Times can be changed but forexample 1.approaches > 2. approaches won't change anyhere. @JohnB

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirement if you are sure that you will need to get all list type together frequently(by looking at the image I will recommend the second one as you need them all together) then use the second method and modify it to accept a list type param and written type to a dictionary something like below else go with the first approach

```
public Dictionary<string,List<string>> getAllComboboxBindingLists(string listTypes)
{
   var resultList = new  Dictionary<string,List<string>>>();
   resultList.Add('carTypes',new List<string>{"sgh","shd","dfh"});
   resultList.Add('studentTypes',new List<string>{"dfg","fgh","dhh"});
   if(listTypes != null)//here listtypes will be a semicolon spllitted string like 'type1;type2'
   {
    var splittedList=listTypes.split(';');
     resultList=resultList.where(r=> splittedList.Contains(r.key))
   }
   return resultList;
}
```

then on your UI, you can easily differentiate the list by key and if need to get a particular list type than send it as a param

Comment: Thanks. No, I need in other page forexample, "getUniversityNames". But in second  approach, we can't access only getUniversityNames. But my main question is , Is second approach is much more performant from second. I thougt that, going 20 times is getting tired the server. Is my thought true? @jitender

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/252375/278720 may help you to decide

Comment: It's useful article for me. I understand from that article that, first approach should be used because of server caching. It's not important of going server 20 times. And not getting tired server forexample 2.000.000 request instead of  100.000 request. There is no difference for server. **Am I right?** @jitender